# Dois Resultados em uma consulta

Tags: sql

Tenho o seguinte exemplo, duas tabelas relacionadas

```
Tabela SETOR
SetorID [chave]
Setor
Vagas



Tabela FUNCIONARIOS
FuncionarioID[chave]
SetorID[chave estrangeira]
Nome
Funcao
CargaHoraria
```

Gostaria de fazer um consulta SQL filtrando pelo *ID do Setor*, aonde o resultado seja o seguinte:

Seja exibido os dados do Setor e os funcionários vinculados a este setor.

Comment: Qual banco de dados? o que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Por favor, especifique qual banco de dados você está utilizando, apesar de conceitos parecidos, pode haver diferenças de sintaxe de um para outro

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM SETOR NATURAL JOIN FUNCIONARIOS;
```

Dessa forma, todos os funcionários serão mostrados com o seu setor do lado, caso precise filtrar as colunas é só trocar o * pelas colunas que você precisa.

Como você tem a coluna SetorID nas duas tabelas, pode usar um NATURAL JOIN, que simplifica o SQL mas é o mesmo que você fizesse FUNCIONARIOS.SetorID = SETOR.SetorId

Comment: eu acho que não fui claro na minha pergunta.
eu gostaria de fazer um filtro na consulta, um where com o SetorID, aonde o resultado seja , o setor filtrado e os funcionarios vinculados a este setor.

Comment: @ErisonNicodemos acho que você não entendeu muito bem como funciona o SQL.. Os resultados de uma query SQL sao sempre linhas de uma tabela (que formam uma tabela nova), mas pra fins didaticos vamos pensar nelas como linhas. O resultado da query que eu coloquei ali, seria um conjunto de linhas da sua tabela, com a listagem dos funcionarios e do lado o seu setor, voce pode filtrar pra aparecer apenas o nome do funcionario e o setor (no SELECT) mas o resultado eh uma tabela, nao é uma coluna com todos os nomes, e outra coluna com todos os nomes. Dê uma estudada em SQL que vai entender

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A.SETORID, SETOR, VAGAS, B.NOME FROM SETOR A 
INNER JOIN FUNCIONARIOS B ON A.SETORID=B.SETORID
WHERE A.SETORID = XXX
```

Desta forma você une as duas tabelas pelo SETORID e traz as informações que necessita de ambas numa consulta só. Lembrando que o INNER é usado quando queremos trazer informações que contenham em ambas tabelas.